# Python Object ID

Tags: python, json, database, list, objectid

I would like create a object ID in python, I explain:

I know that exist mysql, sqlite, mongoDB, etc... But I would like at least create a object ID for store data in json.

Before I was putting the json info inside of a list and the ID was the index of this json in the list, for example:

```
data = [{"name": userName}]
data[0]["id"] = len(data) - 1
```

Then I realize that was wrong and obviously dont look like objectID, then I thought in that the ID can be the Date and Time together, but I thought was wrong too, so, I would like know the best way for make like a objectID, that represent this json inside the list. this list will be more longer, is for users or clients (is just a personal project). And how can be a example of a method for create the ID

Thanks so much, hope I explained good.

Comment: "Then I realize that was wrong and obviously dont look like objectID" why is it wrong? why doesn't it look like an object id? what exactly are you looking for? If it is just going to be the index, why do you need it as a part of the dict at all?

Comment: Also, please note, there is no JSON here. JSON is a text-based serialization format. You have a dict inside a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create a locally unique value, you could use a really simple autoincrement approach.

```
data = [
    {"name": "Bill"},
    {"name": "Javier"},
    {"name": "Jane"},
    {"name": "Xi"},
    {"name": "Nosferatu"},
]

current_id = 1

for record in data:
    record["id"] = current_id
    current_id += 1
    print(record)
# {'name': 'Bill', 'id': 1}
# {'name': 'Javier', 'id': 2}
# {'name': 'Jane', 'id': 3}
# {'name': 'Xi', 'id': 4}
# {'name': 'Nosferatu', 'id': 5}
```

To add a new value if you're not initializing like this, you can get the last one with `max(d.get("id", 0) for d in data)`.

This may cause various problems depending on your use case. If you don't want to worry about that, you could also throw UUIDs at it; they're heavier but easy to generate with reasonable confidence of uniqueness.

```
from uuid import uuid4

data = [{"name": "Conan the Librarian"}]
data[0]["id"] = str(uuid4())
print(data)
# 'id' will be different each time; example:
# [{'name': 'Conan the Librarian', 'id': '85bb4db9-c450-46e3-a027-cb573a09f3e3'}]
```

Without knowing your actual use case, though, it's impossible to say whether one, either, or both of these approaches would be useful or appropriate.

Comment: Thanks so much... My case is that Im trying to do a small inventory with clients, similar like POS, but if just for me, I'm making a small business and I would like do my own software, I already have it and is working, but I would like it be and look more professional possible. The UUID looks very good, I think I will go with that. I dont know if hide the ID row or put the ID like a property inside the RowWidget class (I'm using PyQt5) doing: `MyQwidgetItem.id = str(userIDHere)`..

Comment: If you're going to be running a small business on this software, I'd strongly suggest either using something open source that does what you need or hiring someone experienced to handle development. If you choose to do it yourself, you should _absolutely_ be using an RDBMS like PostgreSQL (or even SQLite), not rolling your own storage scheme. There's really no reason to reinvent the wheel here and it adds unnecessary risk to your business.